# How do I include a column for lookup, but exclude it from GROUP BY?

Tags: python, django, orm

I am trying to execute the following query using the Django ORM:

```
SELECT object_repr, content_type_id, COUNT(object_repr) 
FROM django_admin_log GROUP BY object_repr ORDER BY COUNT(object_repr);
```

The closest I have gotten is:

```
LogEntry.objects.values('object_repr', 'content_type__id')\
                .annotate(num_logs=Count('object_repr'))\
                .order_by('num_logs')
```

Unfortunately this yields a SQL statement that returns the wrong (or, at least, an unexpected)  result:

```
SELECT `django_admin_log`.`object_repr`, `django_admin_log`.`content_type_id`, 
COUNT(`django_admin_log`.`object_repr`) AS `num_logs` 
FROM `django_admin_log` 
GROUP BY `django_admin_log`.`object_repr`, `django_admin_log`.`content_type_id` 
ORDER BY num_logs
```

The values() method includes all specified columns in the "GROUP BY" segment, and I don't want `content_type_id` in my GROUP BY. Is it even possible to do this in the ORM?

**edit:** Turns out this is not possible in the ORM. However in the interest of future people finding this question, the query I wrote which does what I need is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT djl2.id, djl1.object_id, djl1.object_repr,
                         djl1.content_type_id,
                         COUNT(djl1.content_type_id) AS num_items
FROM django_admin_log AS djl1
    INNER JOIN django_admin_log AS djl2
    ON djl1.id=djl2.id
GROUP BY djl1.object_repr, djl1.content_type_id
ORDER BY num_items
```

Basically a self inner join. Good luck, and hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually just went through this in the last few days and posted a question but it is not as well worded as yours in my opinion.

Anyway, what I found is that while Sqlite and MySql will not give an error when you run a query where you select columns not found in the group by clause, those results may be somewhat dubious as the standard for sql apparently is to not allow this.  I know MSSQL will return an error when you attempt this, I'm not sure about other flavors of sql.

Based on this I have come to the conclusion that django doesn't allow generating a query like that through the ORM because it technically isn't valid even though it may work to some extent on some flavors of SQL.

Here is the link to my question for reference: [Can I control the GROUP BY in django 1.3's orm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835355/can-i-control-the-group-by-in-django-1-3s-orm)

Comment: I see. The following is very interesting: "...MySql will not give an error when you run a query where you select columns not found in the group by clause..." If nothing else, this gives me another avenue to explore.

Comment: You want to select a column (content_type__id) that is not in the group by clause, correct?  That is exactly what I was trying to do and I found that it is not possible to do it in Django because it is not valid to do so in a raw sql statement even though it may work to some extent in some sql flavors.

Comment: Yes, you can play with the raw sql to see how that works on the different sql flavors, it probably won't be very consistent.  I did find this handy link that sort of explains the issue a bit and shows you the different results on different sql flavors, although many of them are not working. http://sqlzoo.net/howto/source/u.cgi/err979/mysql

Comment: I want to SELECT **object_repr**, content_type_id, COUNT(object_repr) ... GROUP BY **object_repr** ... but in the example you linked to this is permissible behavior. _edit_: Oh, I see it doesn't work in all flavors. Bummer.

Comment: I added the SQL statement to my original question that got me to where I needed to go. Thanks for your crucial insight.